# Eclipse does not return to the beginning of the file in Find/Replace

Tags: eclipse, replace, eclipse-indigo, helios

When I use Find/Replace in Eclipse (Helios Service Release 2), it does not find the words above my current location even it reaches to the end of file and I have to set Direction to Backward.

I remember the eclipse (maybe indigo) was returning to the beginning of file when it reached to the end.

Is there any setting for this?

Comment: There is the 'Wrap search' option on the Find/Replace dialog itself.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, I did not know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the greg-449's answer: There is the 'Wrap search' option on the Find/Replace dialog itself.

Answer (score 12):

As you have already found the answer. Just adding the official page which describes this feature in eclipse.There is a wrap search option for this.

From the **[docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-181.htm)**:-

> Select the Wrap Search checkbox if you want the dialog to continue
>   from the top of the file once the bottom is reached (if you find /
>   replace in Selected Lines only, then this option applies to those
>   lines only)

Below is the screen shot for the same:-

[image]

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about the working and upvoting of SO but I found that when people put efforts in there answer even if it is answered then it is acknowledged. And I did the same :)

Answer (score 3):

See attached screen shot below. You also hear a DING when the search wraps over to the beginning of the file.

http://www.screencast.com/t/7ss2li9Ah